# Mysterious white bar at the top of the root view controller

Tags: ios

**SOLVED**

I'm trying to find out why this white bar is always present at the top of my app's root view controller, no matter the class of this view controller, and regardless of whether I load the view controller from the storyboard or a xib. When the app loads, the white animates down a little from the top of the view. I hid the status bar. I've included the relevant code below. Here's what the root view controller currently looks like:

[image]

I did nothing to the default implementation of the root view controller except change it's view's background color in IB.

Here's the view controller's xml in the story board:

```
    <!--Temp Root View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="6uA-oJ-W1v">
        <objects>
            <viewController storyboardIdentifier="IOTempRootViewController" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="UCT-Xp-tcq" customClass="IOTempRootViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="C0w-an-LnL">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Lwh-bk-ydQ" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="-202" y="114"/>
    </scene>
```

Here's the root view controller in the storyboard:

[image]

Where else can I look to find the source of the white bar?

Answer (score 2):

It's the navigation bar.

`navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has replied to your question, it must be one of those quirky things that only you can debug.

Never the less try this

- Build --> Clean your project
- Close your project and remove all files from DeriveData directory
- Launch your project
- In storyboard add a brand new viewcpmtroller and delete the old problematic one.
- Build and launch your app.

See if this helps.

**EDIT:**

I just realized your problem. Is your app universal? Are you using the same storyboard for iPhone and iPad? Your simulator screenshot shows an iPad yet storyboard shows iPhone 5 viewcontroller.

Comment: I did all of that. I cleaned my project remove all contents of deriveddata, relaunched my project, and used a fresh XIB instead of using the view controller in the storyboard. My app only targets the iPhone, not the iPad.